# Função hnp - Pacote hnp do R

Tags: r, glmer

O meu modelo foi criado com a função glmer, do pacete `lme4`. É um modelo linear generalizado misto, com resposta Binomial.

```
form=status~(A1+A2+  B1 + ... + B10 +  (1 | escola))

Mod1 <- glmer(form, data = dadosesc, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer =  "optimx", optCtrl=list(method="nlminb")), 
        nAGQ = 25)
```

Sendo status 0 ou 1, A1 e  A2 e escola  categoricas e as demais continuas.

Estou tentando utilizar a função `hnp`, do pacote `hnp`, para criar um envelope simulado da seguinte forma

```
hnp(Mod1, xlab="Half-normal scores", ylab="Deviance residuals", pch=3)
```

mas está apresentando o seguinte erro:

```
Error in simulate(object)[, 1][, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions.
```

Somente consigo quando utilizo uma binomial simples formado com GLM.

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e disponibilize o código utilizado para ajustar o GLMM Binomial. Pode ser que haja uma má especificação do modelo e esta seja a razão do erro. Até onde sei, a função `hnp` trabalha de maneira correta com os objetos da classe glmerMod.

Comment: @MarcusNunes, fiz a alteração sugerida,

Comment: Que esquisito. O modelo parece ter sido bem definido. Teria como editar o post mais uma vez com o resultado de `dput(dadosesc)`? Assim, o teu conjunto de dados seria partilhado conosco e seria possível, para a gente, reproduzir o teu problema.

Answer (score 1):

No [help da função `hnp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hnp/hnp.pdf) (páginas 11 e 12 deste documento), você pode ver a lista de modelos que podem ser utilizado. Modelos feitos com o pacote `glmer` não constam nessa lista.

Pelo help, você pode ver também que é possível construir este gráfico para um modelo não implementado. Neste caso você precisará fornecer três funções:

- simfun: simula números aleatórios com a distribuição do modelo
- fitfun: ajusta um modelo novamente
- diagfun: calcula a medida de diagnóstico para a qual você quer fazer o envelope.

Por exemplo, considere o seguinte banco de dados:

```
df <- data_frame(
  x1 = runif(100, min = 0, max = 0.5),
  x2 = runif(100, min = 0, max = 0.5),
  y = as.factor(rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = x1 + x2))
)
df
# A tibble: 100 × 3
           x1         x2      y
        <dbl>      <dbl> <fctr>
1  0.05263752 0.44304477      1
2  0.23866105 0.38094325      1
3  0.16474934 0.12541530      0
4  0.47944698 0.46145428      1
5  0.31256457 0.01484219      1
6  0.28411475 0.17338685      1
7  0.34083505 0.35194770      0
8  0.30603019 0.40298573      1
9  0.22193441 0.44697690      1
10 0.36469374 0.34312517      1
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Neste exemplo `y` é diretamente relacionado a `x1` e `x2`.

Ajustando um modelo misto neste caso, e rodando a funçãpo `hnp` obtenho o mesmo erro que você:

```
fit_glmer <- glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | x1), data = df, family = "binomial")
hnp(fit_glmer)
Binomial-normal model 
Error in `[.default`(simulate(object)[, 1], , 1) : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Isso acontecxe porque nenhum método está implementado para lidar com objetos do tipo `glmer`. Vamos então implementar as funções necessárias para a construção do gráfico:

```
diagfun <- function(obj) {
  resid(obj, type="pearson")
}

simfun <- function(n, obj) {
  as.factor(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = predict(obj, type = "response")))
}

fitfun <- function(y.) {
  glmer(y. ~ x1 + x2 + (1 | x1), data = df, family = "binomial")
}
```

Agora você pode chamar a função `hnp` desta forma:

```
hnp(fit_glmer, newclass=TRUE, diagfun=diagfun, simfun=simfun, fitfun=fitfun)
```

Ela produzirá o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro, este é apenas um exemplo, você precisará adaptar este código para o seu problema específico. A princípio, acredito que o único lugar que você precisa mexer é na função `fitfun`. Talvez você precise mexer na função `diagfun`, se quiser que o tipo de resíduo não seja Pearson por exemplo (vi na legenda do seu gráfico que você usa resíduos deviance).